# How to Display images 100x75, and on click, display them in original size.  ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

The code below first displays folders as hyperlinks, you can click into these folders and if they contain JPG's it will display them.

Is it possible to make these images display with attributes width="100" height="75" but still allow me to click them and have them display original size?

```
<%
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

qfolder = request.querystring("f")
if qfolder = "" then
    folderspec = server.mappath(".")
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(folderspec) 
    Set folcoll = demofolder.SubFolders
    For Each subfol in folcoll
        folsize = left((subfol.size/1000000), 3)
        folist = folist & "<a href='?f=" & subfol.name & "'><strong title='view'></strong> " & subfol.Name & "" & vbcrlf
        folist = folist & "<BR>"  
    Next
    set filesys = nothing
    Response.Write folist

else

filepath = server.mappath(".") & "\" & qfolder
captionfile = filepath & "\captions.txt"
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim SomeArray()
'caption part
    If filesys.FileExists(captionfile) then
        set file = filesys.GetFile(captionfile)
        Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading,TristateUseDefault)
        captioncount = 0
        Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream
            Line = TextStream.readline
            ReDim Preserve SomeArray(captioncount)
            SomeArray(captioncount) = line
            'response.write captioncount & " " & somearray(captioncount) & "<br>"
            captioncount = captioncount + 1
            'Response.write Line
        Loop
        textStream.close
    end if

'folder part
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(filepath) 
    Set filecoll = demofolder.Files
    filecount = 0
    For Each file in filecoll
        Ext = UCase(Right(File.Path, 3)) 
        If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" Then
        on error resume next
        data = SomeArray(filecount)
        on error goto 0
        hrefpath = qfolder & "/" & file.name
        imagepath = "<strong>" & data & "</strong><br><a href='" & hrefpath & "' title='free image gallery' border=0><img src='" & hrefpath & "' border='" & border_size & "' title=""" & data & """ style='border-color: " & border_color & ";'></a><br>"
        filist = filist & imagepath & vbcrlf
        filist = filist & "<BR>"
        filecount = filecount + 1
        data = ""
        end if
    Next
    set filesys = Nothing
    filist = filist & "<br><small><a href='http://www.allscoop.com/' target='_blank'>allscoop free image gallery</a></small>"
%>

<h3><a href="." title="up one level">&#171;</a>
&nbsp;<%=qfolder%></h3>

<p><%=filist%></p>

<% end if %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to update a single line where  tag is created:

```
imagepath = "<strong>" & data & "</strong><br><a href='" & hrefpath & _
       "' title='free image gallery' border=0><img width=100 height=75 src='" &_
       hrefpath & "' border='" & border_size & "' title=""" & data &_
       """ style='border-color: " & border_color & ";'></a><br>"
```

Just in case here is complete script:

```
<%
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

qfolder = request.querystring("f")
if qfolder = "" then
    folderspec = server.mappath(".")
    Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(folderspec) 
    Set folcoll = demofolder.SubFolders
    For Each subfol in folcoll
        folsize = left((subfol.size/1000000), 3)
        folist = folist & "<a href='?f=" & subfol.name & "'><strong title='view'></strong> " & subfol.Name & "" & vbcrlf
        folist = folist & "<BR>"  
    Next
    set filesys = nothing
    Response.Write folist

else

filepath = server.mappath(".") & "\" & qfolder
captionfile = filepath & "\captions.txt"
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim SomeArray()
'caption part
    If filesys.FileExists(captionfile) then
        set file = filesys.GetFile(captionfile)
        Set TextStream = file.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading,TristateUseDefault)
        captioncount = 0
        Do While Not TextStream.AtEndOfStream
            Line = TextStream.readline
            ReDim Preserve SomeArray(captioncount)
            SomeArray(captioncount) = line
            'response.write captioncount & " " & somearray(captioncount) & "<br>"
            captioncount = captioncount + 1
            'Response.write Line
        Loop
        textStream.close
    end if

'folder part
    Set demofolder = filesys.GetFolder(filepath) 
    Set filecoll = demofolder.Files
    filecount = 0
    For Each file in filecoll
        Ext = UCase(Right(File.Path, 3)) 
        If Ext = "JPG" OR Ext = "GIF" Then
        on error resume next
        data = SomeArray(filecount)
        on error goto 0
        hrefpath = qfolder & "/" & file.name
        imagepath = "<strong>" & data & "</strong><br><a href='" & hrefpath & "' title='free image gallery' border=0><img width=100 height=75 src='" & hrefpath & "' border='" & border_size & "' title=""" & data & """ style='border-color: " & border_color & ";'></a><br>"
        filist = filist & imagepath & vbcrlf
        filist = filist & "<BR>"
        filecount = filecount + 1
        data = ""
        end if
    Next
    set filesys = Nothing
    filist = filist & "<br><small><a href='http://www.allscoop.com/' target='_blank'>allscoop free image gallery</a></small>"
%>

<h3><a href="." title="up one level">&#171;</a>
&nbsp;<%=qfolder%></h3>

<p><%=filist%></p>

<% end if %>
```